# Is the word 'Jati' in the sense of caste used anywhere in Vedas?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, atharva-veda

I have read the word 'Jati' used in Nirukta XII,13 Krishna Jatiya (Black by birth) in the later Vedic literature. And also Dr. Ambedkar pointed out the word Jati has used even in Atharva Veda by quoting a western scholar.  Can we find the term Jati used as in any such meaning even in Atharva Veda?

Comment: Though your question specifically asks otherwise, you may want to have a general look at both answers here- [the difference between varna and jati](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/39863/20129)